# arcpy query not working

Tags: python, select, arcgis, arcpy

I have an ArcPy script that is meant to select the desired attributes (both `E-dom` and `E-subdom` – see example below) from an attribute table based on a query.

```
myQuery = '"VM_POLY" = \'E-dom\'' or '"VM_POLY" = \'E-subdom\''
myInputShapeFile = r"D:\FieldStudy.shp"
myOutputShapefile = r"D:\Endangered.shp"

arcpy.Select_analysis(myInputShapeFile, myOutputShapefile, myQuery)
```

When the script is finished, only one type of attribute from the query is selected. In the attribute table for `myInputShapeFile`, there is both `E-dom` and `E-subdom` attributes, but the script will only return `E-dom` in the `myOutputShapefile`. I know the problem is possibly in the query (`myQuery`) but I am not sure how to resolve it.

If someone could provide some guidance, it would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you got your apostrophes wrong?

```py
myQuery = '"VM_POLY" = \'E-dom\'' or '"VM_POLY" = \'E-subdom\''
#         ^             ¨      ¨^    ^             ¨         ¨^
```

(Apostrophes marked by a `^` delimit a Python string; those marked with `¨` are escaped and therefore part of the string.)

I suppose your query ought to be:

```py
myQuery = '"VM_POLY" = \'E-dom\' or "VM_POLY" = \'E-subdom\''
#         ^             ¨      ¨                 ¨         ¨^
```

because the `or` should not be interpreted by Python (logical operator applied to two strings), but should be part of the query text.

Comment: Yep, this solved the issue that I had..Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myQuery = '"VM_POLY" = "E-dom" or "VM_POLY"= "E-subdom"'
```

As was stated the `or` operator was being mishandled because it was not within the confines of your quotation. You also had the `escape character \` in there which probably was not needed but you were attempting to work around the fact that your `or` operator was exposed and not part of the SQL query and thus picked up by the Python interpreter instead.

Answer (score 1):

Python string formatting (and the SQL "IN" operator) make it (slightly) easier to handle the complex quote syntax:

```
myQuery = "\"{}\" IN ('{}', '{}')".format("VM_POLY", "E-dom", "E-subdom")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your query with specifiers.

```
myQuery = ' "%s" = %s or "%s" = %s ' %('VM_POLY','E-dom','VM_POLY','E-subdom')
```

I know it seems quirky at first but its a good way to ensure your quotes and double quotes are positioned correctly for such things that require specific formatting. They have become my best friend as of late.

NOTE: if you have numbers you would like to inject into the string you can do so by using %d instead of %s.